# The .asm file below compiles and builds as expected but the linker emits a warning. I'd like to know why the warning

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker-warning

As can be seen in the picture below, the Output window for the Build shows the following linker warning:

`warning LNK4258: directive '/ENTRY:main@0' not compatible with switch '/ENTRY:main'; ignored`

What exactly is being warned here?

[image]

Comment: `END main` already specifies the entry point. You do not need to specify it in the settings panel. `stdcall` appends the `@0` suffix but the panel doesn't so the linker sees two different values, hence the conflict.

Comment: @Jester Great! Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Please cut & paste your source code and error messages as text into posts.

Comment: @RossRidge I'll do that in my next post.

Comment: @Jester Could you provide a link documenting what you wrote above?

Comment: The [microsoft documentation for the END directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/end-masm) and the [stdcall convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall)

Comment: @Jester Now everything makes sense. Thanks.